# Overwrite interface method signature with specific in sub class

Tags: php, oop

I'm currently trying to implement the [RepositoryPattern](https://www.thinktocode.com/2019/01/24/doctrine-repositories-should-be-collections-without-flush/) with strict types enabled in PHP. But I'm running into the following error:

> Declaration must be compatible with DoctrineServiceInterface->create(entity: \Service\EntityInterface)

I'd like to create a base interface and become more and more specific in the subclasses. Isn't this the correct way of doing this? How can I achieve something like this in PHP?

## Interfaces

```
interface EntityInterface {

}

interface ReportInterface extends EntityInterface {

}

interface DoctrineServiceInterface
{
    public function create(EntityInterface $entity): void;
}
```

## Entities

```
abstract class AbstractEntity implements EntityInterface
{
    protected ?string $id = null;
}

abstract class ReportEntity extends AbstractEntity implements ReportInterface {

}

class ReportDailyEntity extends ReportEntity {

}

class ReportMonthlyEntity extends ReportEntity {

}
```

## Services

```
abstract class AbstractDoctrineService implements DoctrineServiceInterface
{
    public function create(EntityInterface $snapshot): void
    {
        // persist using repository
    }
}

class ReportService extends AbstractDoctrineService
{
    // How to overcome this error here:
    // -> Declaration must be compatible with DoctrineServiceInterface->create(entity: \Service\EntityInterface)
    public function create(ReportInterface $report): void
    {
        parent::create($report);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's problem is with `namespace`! can you write `namespace` of each one?

Comment: They are all in the same namespace. I don't see an error in my code. I've read all about the Liskov substitution principle but I don't understand why this is not allowed. Full covariance and contravariance support was added in PHP 7.4. So this must be possible. Parameters which are more specific should be a thing, rigth?

Comment: No, not right. Read the dupe (and the docs) more carefully. _"[Full] contravariance allows a parameter type to be less specific in a child method, than that of its parent"_ In the linked dupe it's explained why this makes sense.